# curl python using response

Tags: python, curl, request

I am trying to replicate the below `curl` command in python using the `requests` module. The `curl` command is as follows:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/{username}/{appname}/push/notifications" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "X-API-Token: Token" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{  \"notification_target\": null,  \"notification_content\": {    \"name\": \"Nazwa\",    \"title\": \"Lampa\",    \"body\": \"Została wyłączona\"  }}"
```

I've try code below but return code 400

```
import requests
h={'accept': 'application/json', 'X-API-Token':'TOKEN','Content-Type':'application/json'}
d={'\"notification_target\": null,  \"notification_content\": {    \"name\": \"Nazwa\",    \"title\": \"Lampa\",    \"body\": \"Została wyłączona\"'}
r = requests.post("https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/{username}/{appname}/push/notifications", data=d, headers=h)
```

Comment: So, what did you acomplish so far? Any errors? Show us your code.

Comment: Define your data as a dict and use the json-keyword instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "null" in python i have to write None and everything is working :)